# How do we dynamically add rows according to the first row elements in a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I have a html table like this

```
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>del</th>    
    </tr> 
   
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="a"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="b"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="del" value="delete"></td>    
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

I want to create a new row in the bottom of a table using the first row html elements(inside `<td>`). But before creating a new row it has to satisfy this condition

```
Condition:
     At least one of the textboxes in any given row should be not empty
```

We can delete any row by clicking on the corresponding delete button in the row.

How do we dynamically add rows according to the first row elements in a table using javascript?

**EDIT:**

Tried to append the row codes to the table using `append` as well as `insertRow` methods but both didn't work.

```
mytable = document.getElementById("myTable");

newrow = `<tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="a"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="b"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" id="del" value="delete"></td>

        </tr>`;

mytable.append(newrow);
mytable.insertRow(newrow);
```

Comment: So, what's your actual question then? I see the question's title. Are you trying to work out if column A or B's input contain any text, are you trying to work out how to make a new row, perhaps you're after instructions for something different. It's not clear

Answer (score 0):

First, create the final table row you want in the table and set its display property to none.
Then use javascript to determine if the fields you want are not empty. If none of the fields are empty, set the final row's display property to block or inline-block.

```
<style>
  #last-row{display: none;}
<style>

<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>del</th>    
    </tr> 
   
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="a"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="b"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="del" value="delete"></td>
        <td id="last-row">ROW CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var a  = document.getElementById("a").value;
var b = document.getElementById("b").value;

if(a && b){
document.getElementById("last-row").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="js-row">
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

We use the [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#direct_children) to retrieve all the elements we need:

```
const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const table = form.querySelector(":scope > table > tbody");
const firstRow = table.querySelector(".js-row");
```

We can append a new row by [cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the first row:

```
function appendTableRow() {
 const cloned = firstRow.cloneNode(true);

 // clear input values
 cloned.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((i) => {
   i.value = "";
 });

 table.append(cloned);
}
```

To validate the condition that 'At least one of the textboxes in any given row should be not empty', we [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) over each of the rows to see if [at least one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of their inputs has a value. In this example, an empty string is considered to be 'not empty':

```
function checkForInvalidRow() {
  const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll(".js-row"));
  const hasValue = (input) => input.value !== "";

  return rows.some((row) => {
    const inputs = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'));
    return !inputs.some(hasValue);
  });
}
```

The inputs can be checked by using the [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event#event_delegation) to add the `blur` event to the `form` element.

```
form.addEventListener(
  "blur",
  (event) => {
    if (!checkForInvalidRow()) {
      appendTableRow();
    }
  },
  true
);
```

Full example:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const table = form.querySelector(":scope > table > tbody");
const firstRow = table.querySelector(".js-row");

form.addEventListener(
  "blur",
  (event) => {
    if (!checkForInvalidRow()) {
      appendTableRow();
    }
  },
  true
);

function checkForInvalidRow() {
  const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll(".js-row"));
  const hasValue = (input) => input.value !== "";

  return rows.some((row) => {
    const inputs = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'));
    return !inputs.some(hasValue);
  });
}

function appendTableRow() {
  const cloned = firstRow.cloneNode(true);

  cloned.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((i) => {
    i.value = "";
  });

  table.append(cloned);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="js-row">
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```